# Transparent Label Control in Flexgrid VB6

Tags: vb6

I have searched and tried to make transparent label on visual basic 6 but still can not, i also tried using (trlbl.dll) the result also can not transparent, i also tried using windows API and still can not, I want the label to be above flexgrid and its font looks transparent?

[image: This sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a UserControl that is setup to be transparent, you'll just need to place your labels onto it to show your text.  See here for more details:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241732(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Thank you will i try, are you any examples of existing guys ?

Comment: I've done this before so I know it works, if that is what you mean.  You don't even have to write code, it is all configured right through the property editor.